Redis failover to Elasticache with `CLIENT PAUSE`
So I'm trying to zero in the process to failover a self-provisioned Redis to ElastiCache. What I'm planning to do:

Start migration in ElastiCache
Multi-exec CLIENT PAUSE 300000 WRITE + INFO replication in the local Redis to get the master_repl_offset.
Once I see master_repl_offset in ElastiCache matches the paused offset, I plan to complete the ElastiCache migration which will promote ElastiCache to primary.
Reconfigure my application to connect to ElastiCache instead of the local Redis.

Now I have some questions:
What will happen after 300000ms elapse and my clients are unpaused? I assume they will hit my local Redis, possibly leading to a undesirable multimaster situation. What should I do to prevent this?
Decommission the local Redis before the CLIENT PAUSE expires?
Issue CLIENT KILL TYPE normal in my local Redis before the timeout?
I have configured my application to retry on IO exceptions, so I should be able to recover from the CLIENT KILL.
Is there a recommended way to do this? I'm not sure I'm not the first one to run into this.
